# Global Variables using Quoted vs. Unquoted Heredocs

Tags: bash, awk, ssh, pipe, heredoc

I'm curious if I can have my cake and eat it too. I'm writing a script that needs to find the directory with the most recent date on a remote server. I then need to build that path so I can find specific .csv files on the server.

The script takes an input called `folder` and it needs to be appended to the end of the path. I've noticed I can pass folder into the heredoc and have it expanded, but then I lose out on the awk expansion I need to do. Here is an example:

```
folder='HBEP'
ssh $server /bin/bash << EOF
ls -t /projects/bison/git |
head -1 |
awk -v folder=$folder '{print "projects/bison/git/"$1"/assessment/LWR/validation/"folder}'
EOF
```

This produces a close but wrong output:

```
# output:
/projects/bison/git//assessment/LWR/validation/HBEB

# should be:
/projects/bison/git/bison_20190827/LWR/validation/HBEP
```

Now, when I quote EOF, I can access the piped in variable but not the folder variable:

```
folder='
ssh $server /bin/bash << 'EOF'
ls -t /projects/bison/git |
head -1 |
awk -v folder="$folder" '{print "projects/bison/git/"$1"/assessment/LWR/validation/"folder}'
EOF
```

```
# output:
projects/bison/git/bison_20190826/assessment/LWR/validation/

# should be:
projects/bison/git/bison_20190826/assessment/LWR/validation/HBEP
```

Is there a way I can leverage expansion in the heredoc and the outside shell?

Comment: Why aren't you using `git` itself to keep track of the most recent version of whatever it is you are tracking?

Comment: Even if you don't use `git`, whatever creates  a new `bison_YYYYMMDD` directory should just maintain a `bison_current` symlink to whichever directory is newest.

Comment: We do, but our nightly tests take forever, so everyday we take the master branch and push it to our cluster. These tests output data files that I need to do some analysis. We don't keep the data files versioned because they are huge.

Comment: @chepner that's a good idea, I'll talk with the person who manages the nightly testing. (Edit: actually I think they wanted a place to keep the history of all the nightly runs, I personally don't see much of a difference than just versioning the master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unquoted version of heredoc. Just add the `\` before `$` if you want to avoid the parameter expansion.

eg

```
folder='HBEP'
ssh $server /bin/bash << EOF
ls -t /projects/bison/git |
head -1 |
awk -v folder=$folder '{print "projects/bison/git/"\$1"/assessment/LWR/validation/"folder}'
EOF
```